# A phrase for something that has a lot of advantages but comes with a lot of problems

Tags: expressions

I'm working on an academic article and need a phrase for a situation where something seems very good, but without the proper tools is useless. 
for example:
Let's say you have Wikipedia with all it's knowledge but no search engine. so it is basically useless.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Could you tell us what words you've tried and why they are not sufficient?

Comment: A fool's errand, that can be called.

Comment: You could say that it **comes with a catch**

Comment: are you just looking for the word "impractical"?

Comment: It's a mixed bag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider the expression "a curate's egg":
kjʊərətsˈɛɡ/
nounBRITISH
a thing that is partly good and partly bad

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curate's_egg
"this book is a bit of a curate's egg"

Answer (score 1):

A [**diamond in the rough**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/diamond+in+the+rough) is anything of value that is not ready for its purpose, but with great potential. Similar to your request, such a diamond *seems very good, but without the proper tools is useless*.

> Diamond in the rough: A person or thing with exceptional qualities or characteristics that cannot be seen from the surface.

Answer (score 0):

An idiomatic expression would be **[as useful as a chocolate teapot](https://www.usingenglish.com/reference/idioms/about+as+useful+as+a+chocolate+teapot.html)**.

> Someone or something that is of no practical use is about as useful as a chocolate teapot.

*usingenglish.com*

While the definition sounds quite harsh, it can be used in situations whereby something seems like it would be obviously useful in a situation, but due to a glaring error it's not.

As per the example in the phrase itself, the problem is that you need to make some tea. At first glance, a teapot would be useful, as it is the proper vessel for brewing a good tea. However, as it is made of chocolate, it serves no use in actually making tea.